# Table of Contents for Math Equations in Latex

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

What's the best way to have equations in LaTeX reference back to a table of contents at the beginning of a document? Something similar to the way that chapters and subchapters easily make a table of contents with `\tableofcontents` at the beginning of a document. Is there a clear method for doing this?